# AttributeError: 'Show' object has no attribute 'get' in Tkinter when using class

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I'm wanna get user data in tkinter in one class I code the some of functions a bit shorter everything is good but when I wanna get data from user it gives me that error which I mention in title.

```
class Show:
    def __init__(self,WindowName=None, place_x=None, place_y=None):
        self.WindowName = WindowName
        self.place_y = place_y
        self.place_x = place_x
    def entry(self):
        global ent
        ent = Entry(self.WindowName)
        ent.place(x=self.place_x, y=self.place_y)
```

then I write a function for using this class:

```
def AutoLoginPage():
    ent0 = Show(WindowName=window, place_x=90, place_y=60)
    ent0.entry()
    ent0.get()
```

in the last line the compiler gives me this error:

```
ent0.get()
AttributeError: 'Show' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Thanks for Helping guys

Comment: have you make a list with entries? if yes try ent[0}.get()

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the `Show` object doesn't have a method named `get`. The error is telling you the truth.

Comment: And it is not a compiler, it is an interpreter.

Comment: According to your code, `ent0.get()` should be `ent.get()` as `ent` is the global variable created inside `Show.entry()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 unfortunately it didn't work for

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich yes my fault!
but do you have any solution for my error?

Comment: @Amin What do you mean *"it didn't work"*? Same error?

Comment: @acw1668 yes it didn't!

Comment: If you change `ent0.get()` to `ent.get()`, you should not get same error.